# Representing iteration of a function in PA

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, peano-arithmetic

Let $\mathscr{L}$ be a (recursive) FOL language, with numeral symbols $\underline{0},\underline{1},\ldots$.  Let $T$ be a recursive, consistent theory, containing PA (or even just Robinson arithmetic).  It is well-known that all computable functions are *strongly represented*.  This means that for any computable function $f\colon \mathbb{N}^k\to \mathbb{N}$ there exists a formula $\varphi(x_1,\ldots, x_k,y)$ in $\mathscr{L}$ (with the free variables as given) such that the following two conditions hold:

(1) $\vdash_T \forall x_1 \cdots \forall x_k \exists y\, \varphi(x_1,\ldots, x_k,y)$.

(2) For any $(m_1,\ldots, m_k,n)\in \mathbb{N}^{k+1}$, we have $f(m_1,\ldots, m_k)=n$ if and only if $\vdash_T \varphi(\underline{m_1},\ldots, \underline{m_k},\underline{n})$.

There are many ways to build new computable functions from old ones.  The standard way to build *all* computable functions is to start with a few initial functions, and take the closure under addition, composition, basic recursion, and $\mu$-minimization; e.g., see [this wiki article about primitive recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function).

Thus, the proof that all computable functions are strongly represented seems clear enough.  Prove it for the initial functions and for those four types of operations.  The hardest step seems to be the basic recursion operation.  Looking through the literature, it appears that the standard proof is to use a clever trick of Godel to encode sequences of numbers.  I wonder if there is any easier proof.

In particular, suppose that $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ is a computable function, and $\varphi(x,y)$ strongly represents it (relative to PA, say).  Define a new function $f^{\square}\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ by the rule that $f^{\square}(m)=\underbrace{f\circ f\circ \cdots \circ f}_{m \text{ times}}(0)$.  In other words, we just iterate $f$ a total of $m$ times, with initial value $0$.  (This is about the simplest version of recursion I can think of.)

**Questions**: What is the simplest way to create a formula that strongly represents $f^{\square}$?  Is there a formula that is *uniform*, in the sense that we can just plug in $\varphi(x,y)$?

Comment: In what sense is the standard Godel coding trick not uniform?

Comment: Use sequence coding, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function .

Comment: I.e. write $\bmod(x,y)=z$ as shorthand for $y | x-z$ and $0 \leq z < y$. Then encode $f^m(0)=n$ as $\exists (L,a,b)$ such that $\bmod(L,a)=0$, $\bmod(L,a+mb)=n$ and, for $0 \leq k < m$, we have $\bmod(L,a+(k+1)b) = f(\bmod(L,a+kb))$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer That certainly answers my question over PA, where one can easily prove that there is a unique remainder.  Is it difficult to modify the idea for Robinson arithmetic?  (I looked at the link Emil gave, which cites Mendelson's textbook.  As far as I can tell, Mendelson works in PA in that book.)

Comment: Representability in $Q$ follows easily from $\Sigma_1$-definability in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, but what about **strong** representability?

Comment: That makes no difference. If $\phi(\vec x,y)$ represents $f$, then $(\phi(\vec x,y)\land\exists!z\,\phi(\vec x,z))\lor(y=0\land\neg\exists!z\,\phi(\vec x,z))$ strongly represents $f$.

Comment: You two are using language I don't understand, but it doesn't seem to me that is there is a good way to define $f^m(0)$ as a total function in $Q$. Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[t]$ and let $R_+$ be the elements in $R$ which have positive leading term. I believe that $R_+$ is a model of $Q$. The function $f(x) = 2x$ is then a perfectly good function in $R_+ \to R_+$, but there is no function $g : Q_+ \to Q_+$ with $g(y+1) = 2 g(y)$. You can still do the Godel encoding trick above, but it doesn't define a complete function anymore. But perhaps I misunderstand the question.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think I'm starting to understand.  If we take, as part of the definition of representability, that $\vdash_T \forall y\, (\varphi(\underline{m_1},\ldots, \underline{m_k},y)\rightarrow y=\underline{n})$, then the formula you gave works just fine.  What I'm not seeing is how this part of representability "follows easily from $\Sigma_1$-definability in $\mathbb{N}$".  From my understanding, $\Sigma_1$-definability is the condition that, for a relation (not necessarily a function) $R\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{k+1}$, then for any $(m_1,\ldots, m_{k+1})\in \mathbb{N}^{k+1}$, we have ...

Comment: $\vec{m}\in R$ if and only if $\vdash_T \psi(\vec{m})$ (for some formula $\psi$).  It isn't clear to me how that function-like behavior on numerals would follow easily from this definability condition, under the additional condition that $\psi$ is $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: The predecessor of $t$ is $t-1$. Since $t-1$ has positive leading term, it is in $R_+$. Indeed, Wikipedia says "there is a computable model of Q consisting of integer-coefficient polynomials with positive leading coefficient, plus the zero polynomial, with their usual arithmetic. "

Comment: And yes, I failed to include the $0$ polynomial in my description of $R_+$, sorry.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer For some reason I was confusing "leading term" with "constant term" (had my ordering backwards), sorry.  I'm assuming that by $Q_{+}$ you meant $R_{+}$?  I'm a little confused about $g$ though.  Doesn't the function $g(x)=0$ satisfy the recursion $g(y+1)=2g(y)$?

Comment: @PaceNielsen This should be explained in any textbook where these concepts are introduced. If $\psi(\vec x,y)=\exists z\,\theta(\vec x,y,z)$ defines the graph $f$, where $\theta$ is $\Delta_0$, then $\exists w\,(y\le w\land\exists z\le w\,\theta(\vec x,y,z)\land\forall y'\le w\,\forall z'\le w\,(\theta(\vec x,y',z')\to y'=y)))$ represents $f$ in $Q$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer If you want the result to be a provably total function in $Q$, you don’t use sequence coding directly as is; you further need to embellish the formula with witness comparison as in my previous comment to make it univalued on standard arguments, and then use the trick in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369505/representing-iteration-of-a-function-in-pa#comment932996_369505 to make it total. Note that this will give a formula that strongly represents $f^\Box$ in $Q$, but in general it will *not* provably in $Q$ satisfy the recurrence $f^\Box(m+1)=f(f^\Box(m))$.

Comment: ... The latter is not part of the deal, and is in general impossible, as it would lead to an interpretation of PRA in $Q$ (though it *does* trivially work in your example, as pointed out by Pace Nielsen).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you!  Everything is clear now. I think that perhaps part of the problem was that I started by reading the early papers proving that all *partial* computable functions are strongly represented, and your specific trick for making a representation strong doesn't work that easily in that case (as it makes the function defined where it shouldn't be).  If there is an easy way to account for that possibility too, I'd be interested.

Comment: I don’t think I understand what you mean. The difference between representability and strong representability as you defined it in the question is exactly that the latter is required to be provably total in the theory. That’s not possible if at the same time you want it to be undefined on specific inputs.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020025569900164

Comment: I see. Well, in that case, I don’t think you can iterate it in a uniform way. For example, consider a function $f$ that is undefined on $0$, but maps all other numbers to $1$. Then $(f\circ f)(0)$ should be undefined, but if you just take a strong representation $\phi$ of $f$, then the canonical definition of $f\circ f$ using $\phi$ as a black box may well make it provably the constant $1$ function (as $\phi$ *may* happen to provably map all nonzero inputs to $1$, and $0$ to nonzero).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It might be possible to rule out that type of behavior using Corollary 3 of https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?loc=refcit&r=1&refcit=258630&sort=Newest&vfpref=html to make a (non-strong) representation $\phi(x,y)$ such that $\phi(0,0)$ is independent of the theory, and then try to "strongify" that formula. However, I think I'm getting out of my depth now.  Thank you again for clearing up my confusions in respect to total functions!