# How can I prove that primitive recursion “preserves” representability in Peano Arithmetic?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, computability-theory, metamathematics, theories-of-arithmetic

I'm working on my thesis about Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems, and at some point I need to prove that the $\textsf{PA}$ system is able to represent *all* the recursive functions.

By *recursive function* we understand every function obtained from the successor, zero and identities/projections functions and the methods of composition, minimization and primitive recursion. The definition for *representability* is that a function $f:\mathbb{N}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is represented by a formula $\varphi$ in the language of $\textsf{PA}$ iff for any $k_1,...,k_m \in \mathbb{N}$, the formula

$\forall y[\varphi(\overline{k_1},...,\overline{k_m},y) \leftrightarrow (y=\overline{f(k_1,...,k_m)})]$

is a theorem of PA (i.e., iff $\textsf{PA} \vdash \forall y[\varphi(\overline{k_1},...,\overline{k_m},y) \leftrightarrow (y=\overline{f(k_1,...,k_m)})]$), where $\overline{k_i}$ is the *numeral* of $k_i$.

**Now, my question is:**
Formally, to prove that every recursive function is representable, we need to prove that there exist formulas that represent the three basic functions (successor, zero and identities), and that the three methods (composition, minimization and primitive recursion) "preserve" representability -- i.e., that given any functions $f,g$ that are representable in $\textsf{PA}$, then $f \circ g$ is representable, and so are the functions obtained from them by minimization and primitive recursion.

The problem is that I *cannot* find a reference where the last of these affirmations is proved. All the books I've searched do just the work of proving the cases of composition and minimization, and then they simply say that the case of primitive recursion is too hard (or they, as Boolos does in his *Computability and Logic*, simply give the formula that represents the proccess -- making the correspondence between this process and a sequence of computations --, without proving by the definition of representability).

At least, finally I found the information, in Richard Zach's *Open Introduction to Gödel's Theorems*, that, in some way, we can "simulate" primitive recursion just using composition and minimization. So it makes sense that we really can avoid the hard demonstration for the representability of primitive recursion, but I *still* want to know why this task is *so* avoidable (that is, *how* such a proof goes).

Comment: See e.g. Hájek and Pudlák, Lemma I.1.55. And no, it is not hard at all, once you have sequence coding (which you will need anyway in any self-respecting development of PA).

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reference, Emil.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Shoenfield's textbook "Mathematical Logic" also proves representability by showing how to simulate primitive recursion using composition and minimization.

Comment: Andreas, yes... that is what I use in my work, but I still wanted to know the direct proof. Thanks

Comment: Marcello, I asked a similar question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369505/representing-iteration-of-a-function-in-pa  David Speyer's first comment should help answer your question.